# Unable to get the results of sql query via php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to use PDO to get the results of a sql query, but unfortunately I only get the output "Array()". As far as I can tell the database is connecting and the query itself is working but I get no results where I am expecting some garbage data that I have put into the tables.

The view:

```
<?php
        require_once('CRUD.php');
        require_once ('Connect.php');
        require_once ('menu.php');

        $db = connectDatabase::connect();
        $crud = new Crud (); 
        $result = $crud->Read($_POST['formReadTable'], $db); 
        print_r($result);   
        connectDatabase::disconnect();
?>
```

and the control:

```
<?php
 interface iCrud {
 public function Read ($var, $var2);
 }

class Crud implements iCrud {   
public function Read ($selectTable, $db) {  
    $results = $this->getQueryResults ($selectTable, $db);
    $queryResults = $results->fetchAll();
    return $queryResults;           
}

private function getQueryResults ($selectTable, $db) {
    $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM :selectTable");
    $q->bindParam(':selectTable', $selectTable, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    try {
        $q->execute();
        return $q;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Exeption: " .$e->getMessage();
    }
}


}
?>
```

Comment: off topic: if this is pdo preparedstements, you cannot bind table or column names

Comment: @Ghost Yes, this a PDO prepared statement. Then should I take the "Select * ..." out and go $sql = "Select * FROM" . $selectTable or is there a way to use php variables within prepared statements?

Comment: @Ghost also the fact I didn't realize the table names can't be bound was the issue so if you want to submit an answer I'll be happy to mark it as such.

Comment: no need to not enough to be answer anyways, an alternative would be to whitelist tables